# android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

i am currently facing this error. I have tried many ways to try and solve it but to no avail. Please point out to me where went wrong and how can i solve it. Thanks.

The error message:

```
                  android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Here is the java class:

```html
package com.uploadtodatabasevts;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBQueryExpression;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.PaginatedQueryList;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Advisor extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    List<Outfit> outfitList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_advisor);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String results = intent.getStringExtra("results");

        final TextView itemOneID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewItemOneID);
        final TextView itemOneDetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewItemOneDetail);
        final TextView itemOnePrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewItemOnePrice);


        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        outfitList = new ArrayList<Outfit>();
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, outfitList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        final AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
        final DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);

       // final Outfit outfitToFind = new Outfit();
      //  outfitToFind.setItemOne_id("VT0056");


        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //DynamoDB calls go here

                Outfit selectedOutfit = mapper.load(Outfit.class, "22");

                selectedOutfit.getItemOne_id();
                selectedOutfit.getItemOne_detail();
                selectedOutfit.getItemOne_price();

                itemOneID.setText(selectedOutfit.getItemOne_id());
                itemOneDetail.setText(selectedOutfit.getItemOne_detail());
                itemOnePrice.setText(selectedOutfit.getItemOne_price());
                /*
                DynamoDBQueryExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression()
                        .withHashKeyValues(outfitToFind)
                        .withConsistentRead(false);

                PaginatedQueryList<Outfit> result = mapper.query(Outfit.class, queryExpression);
                result.
                */
            }
        };
        Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
        mythread.start();



    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All view operations has to be called on the `main thread` which is the `UI thread`, change your `Runnable` to below

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //DynamoDB calls go here

            Outfit selectedOutfit = mapper.load(Outfit.class, "22");

            selectedOutfit.getItemOne_id();
            selectedOutfit.getItemOne_detail();
            selectedOutfit.getItemOne_price();
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    itemOneID.setText(selectedOutfit.getItemOne_id());
                    itemOneDetail.setText(selectedOutfit.getItemOne_detail());
                    itemOnePrice.setText(selectedOutfit.getItemOne_price());
                }
            });
            /*
            DynamoDBQueryExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression()
                    .withHashKeyValues(outfitToFind)
                    .withConsistentRead(false);

            PaginatedQueryList<Outfit> result = mapper.query(Outfit.class, queryExpression);
            result.
            */
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks ! This solved my issue, but i am currently having trouble passing data from the first page to this page. As i am currently using a qr scanning, i'll be scanning the item ID and passing it to this page to retrieve the data. I've change the mapper.load(Outfit.class, "22") to mapper.load(Outfit.class, results but i faced with this error

Comment: com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMappingException: Null key found for public java.lang.String com.uploadtodatabasevts.Tables.Item.getItem_id()

Comment: nvm i have solved the error. I forgot to add in one line in the other class.